# Insert empty string as NULL and zero as zero into float column

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, null

I have a float column, call it money.

I am trying to insert the 0 value as 0 and the empty string value should be `NULL`

```
INSERT INTO t1 (money) values ('0.00')
INSERT INTO t1 (money) values ('')

SELECT * FROM t1
```

This is the result I am trying to achieve

```
 money
    0
    NULL
```

I tried Using an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger (I used '123' just to visualize which condition is met)

```
iif(CAST(money AS nvarchar) = '', NULL, iif(money < '0.0001', '123', money))

SELECT * FROM t1

money
123
123
```

So it seems that I cannot compare my float column against an empty string.

But when trying following it looks like in fact it is possible:

```
CASE WHEN (money = '' THEN '456' ELSE iif(money < '0.0001', '123', money))

SELECT * FROM t1

money 
456
456
```

Which makes me very unsure of how SQL Server converts those datatypes internally.

Comment: Are you inserting other columns as well? Is the `money` field in your table set to `NOT NULL`? Because if you have other columns and this one is not set to `NOT NULL`, then just don't include it on the insert...

Comment: Re: your last statement, SQL Server's data type conversions are documented on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx

Comment: @johnhc I am inserting alot more columns and alot of them are of type float, all of them are allowed to be NULL.

Comment: Money as float datatype = bad idea.  as for null... `INSERT INTO t1 (money) values (NULL)` or `INSERT INTO t1 (money) values (case when '' = '' then null else '')

Comment: @xQbert the column is in fact AccruedInterest i simplified it for reading purposes as money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm,

you try wierd things if you insert string values into a float-column.

```
INSERT INTO t1 (money) values (nullif('0.00', ''))
```

BUT you should really invest some time in data type conversion from ground up. I would expect the calling application to have an error if someone tried to insert a string into my float-column...

Comment: I like the, "you try wierd things if you insert string values into a float-column." :P

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
declare @valuetobeinserted varchar(20)
set @valuetobeinserted = '0.00'
insert into t1 select case when  @valuetobeinserted = '' then null else @valuetobeinserted end as m

set @valuetobeinserted = ''
insert into t1 select case when  @valuetobeinserted = '' then null else @valuetobeinserted end as m
```